# A differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I totally have no idea about this...
If $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y^2+1}$, then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$=?
The correct answer is $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a few applications of the chain rule and use of the ODE as $\frac d{dx} y(x)$ appears.
$$\begin{align*}
\frac d{dx} \sqrt{y^2(x)+1} & = \frac1{2\sqrt{y^2(x)+1}} \cdot \frac d{dx} (y^2(x) + 1) \\
& = \frac1{2\sqrt{y^2(x)+1}} 2y(x) \cdot y'(x) \\
& \stackrel{\text{ODE}}= \frac1{\sqrt{y^2(x)+1}} \cdot y(x) \cdot \sqrt{y^2(x)+1} \\
& = y(x)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} = \left( \frac{dy}{dx}\right)'$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use chain rule while differentiating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with respect to $x$.